# Scala: specify a default generic type instead of Nothing

Tags: scala, generics

I have a pair of classes that look something like this.  There's a `Generator` that generates a value based on some class-level values, and a `GeneratorFactory` that constructs a `Generator`.

```
case class Generator[T, S](a: T, b: T, c: T) {
  def generate(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S =
    bf() += (a, b, c) result
}

case class GeneratorFactory[T]() {
  def build[S <% Seq[T]](seq: S) = Generator[T, S](seq(0), seq(1), seq(2))
}
```

You'll notice that `GeneratorFactory.build` accepts an argument of type `S` and `Generator.generate` produces a value of type `S`, but there is nothing of type `S` stored by the `Generator`.

We can use the classes like this.  The factory works on a sequence of `Char`, and `generate` produces a `String` because `build` is given a `String`.

```
val gb = GeneratorFactory[Char]()
val g = gb.build("this string")
val o = g.generate
```

This is fine and handles the `String` type implicitly because we are using the `GeneratorFactory`.

---

### The Problem

Now the problem arises when I want to construct a `Generator` without going through the factory.  I would like to be able to do this:

```
val g2 = Generator('a', 'b', 'c')
g2.generate // error
```

But I get an error because `g2` has type `Generator[Char,Nothing]` and Scala "Cannot construct a collection of type Nothing with elements of type Char based on a collection of type Nothing."

What I want is a way to tell Scala that the "default value" of `S` is something like `Seq[T]` instead of `Nothing`.  Borrowing from the syntax for default parameters, we could think of this as being something like:

```
case class Generator[T, S=Seq[T]]
```

---

### Insufficient Solutions

Of course it works if we explicitly tell the generator what its generated type should be, but I think a default option would be nicer (my actual scenario is more complex):

```
val g3 = Generator[Char, String]('a', 'b', 'c')
val o3 = g3.generate  // works fine, o3 has type String
```

I thought about overloading `Generator.apply` to have a one-generic-type version, but this causes an error since apparently Scala can't distinguish between the two `apply` definitions:

```
object Generator {
  def apply[T](a: T, b: T, c: T) = new Generator[T, Seq[T]](a, b, c)
}

val g2 = Generator('a', 'b', 'c')  // error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition
```

---

### Desired Output

What I would like is a way to simply construct a `Generator` without specifying the type `S` and have it default to `Seq[T]` so that I can do:

```
val g2 = Generator('a', 'b', 'c')
val o2 = g2.generate
// o2 is of type Seq[Char]
```

I think that this would be the cleanest interface for the user.

Any ideas how I can make this happen?

Comment: you could create a `SimpleGenerator` and a `ComplexGenerator` both with an apply method ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use a base trait and then narrow `S` as needed in its subclasses? The following for example fits your requirements:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

trait Generator[T] {
  type S
  def a: T; def b: T; def c: T
  def generate(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S = bf() += (a, b, c) result
}

object Generator {
  def apply[T](x: T, y: T, z: T) = new Generator[T] {
    type S = Seq[T]
    val (a, b, c) = (x, y, z)
  }
}

case class GeneratorFactory[T]() {
  def build[U <% Seq[T]](seq: U) = new Generator[T] {
    type S = U
    val Seq(a, b, c, _*) = seq: Seq[T]
  }
}
```

I've made `S` an abstract type to keep it a little more out of the way of the user, but you could just as well make it a type parameter.

Comment: I like this solution since it covers all the cases without too much added complexity.  One thing to note is that making `S` a type parameter means that `generate` has the correct return type (String, Seq[Char], etc) instead of a return type like `g.S`.

Answer (score 4):

This does not directly answer your main question, as I think others are handling that. Rather, it is a response to your request for default values for type arguments.

I have put some thought into this, even going so far as starting to write a proposal for instituting a language change to allow it. However, I stopped when I realized where the Nothing actually comes from. It is not some sort of "default value" like I expected. I will attempt to explain where it comes from.

In order to assign a type to a type argument, Scala uses the most specific possible/legal type. So, for example, suppose you have "class A[T](x: T)" and you say "new A[Int]". You directly specified the value of "Int" for T. Now suppose that you say "new A(4)". Scala knows that 4 and T have to have the same type. 4 can have a type anywhere between "Int" and "Any". In that type range, "Int" is the most specific type, so Scala creates an "A[Int]". Now suppose that you say "new A[AnyVal]". Now, you are looking for the most specific type T such that Int <: T <: Any and AnyVal <: T <: AnyVal. Luckily, Int <: AnyVal <: Any, so T can be AnyVal.

Continuing, now suppose that you have "class B[S >: String <: AnyRef]". If you say "new B", you won't get an B[Nothing]. Rather you will find that you get a B[String]. This is because S is being constrained as String <: S <: AnyRef and String is at the bottom of that range.

So, you see, for "class C[R]", "new C" doesn't give you a C[Nothing] because Nothing is some sort of default value for type arguments. Rather, you get a C[Nothing] because Nothing is the lowest thing that R can be (if you don't specify otherwise, Nothing <: R <: Any).

This is why I gave up on my default type argument idea: I couldn't find a way to make it intuitive. In this system of restricting ranges, how do you implement a low-priority default? Or, does the default out-priority the "choose the lowest type" logic if it is within the valid range? I couldn't think of a solution that wouldn't be confusing for at least some cases. If you can, please let me know, as I'm very interested.

edit: Note that the logic is reversed for contravariant parameters. So if you have "class D[-Q]" and you say "new D", you get a D[Any].

Answer (score 2):

One option is to move the summoning of the `CanBuildFrom` to a place where it (or, rather, its instances) can help to determine `S`,

```
case class Generator[T,S](a: T, b: T, c: T)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]) {
  def generate : S =
    bf() += (a, b, c) result
}
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val g2 = Generator('a', 'b', 'c')
g2: Generator[Char,String] = Generator(a,b,c)

scala> g2.generate
res0: String = abc
```

**Update**

The `GeneratorFactory` will also have to be modified so that its `build` method propagates an appropriate `CanBuildFrom` instance to the `Generator` constructor,

```
case class GeneratorFactory[T]() {
  def build[S](seq: S)(implicit conv: S => Seq[T], bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]) =
    Generator[T, S](seq(0), seq(1), seq(2))
}
```

Not that with Scala < 2.10.0 you can't mix view bounds and implicit parameter lists in the same method definition, so we have to translate the bound `S <% Seq[T]` to its equivalent implicit parameter `S => Seq[T]`.

Comment: This is great for direct construction of `Generator`, but unfortunately it causes a "not enough arguments for method apply" compilation error in `GeneratorFactory.build`.

Comment: @dhg: You can fix that part by adding an implicit argument: `def build[S](seq: S)(implicit conv: S => Seq[T], cbf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]) = ...`.

Comment: The fact that you can't just write `Generator(1, 2, 3)` is still a problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I assume this works for the Char/String case since there's an implicit `Seq[Char] => String` CanBuildFrom in predef?  Unfortunately I'll need it to work even when no implicit CanBuildFrom to be found (as in `Generator(1,2,3)`)