# Default type parameter on method

Tags: scala

```
object Toto {
  def bla[A <: Any](keys: String*): Map[String, A] = ???
  val a = bla("sdfa") // This is of type Map[String, Nothing]
}
```

Can we do so that `A` is `Any` by default and so `bla` returns `Map[String, Any]` if `A` is not specified?

Cheers

Comment: The question is not exactly a duplicate, but the answer to this question provides a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6629984/1632462

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811267/scala-specify-a-default-generic-type-instead-of-nothing