# How to set default type in Scala Numeric Generic Function?

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming

My question is pretty simple.

I've read some possible duplicates like [Scala: specify a default generic type instead of Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811267/scala-specify-a-default-generic-type-instead-of-nothing), [Default generic type on method in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270185/default-generic-type-on-method-in-scala)

But these cases are not same as mine.

```
// define
def sum[T](name: String)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): ...
def sum(name: String) = sum[Double](name)

// use
val a = sum[Long]("name...") // It's OK.
val b = sum("name...") // ERROR: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition
```

I want to use sum("....") same as sumDouble

I really appreciate it if you can give me any hint.

Comment: How about declaring a default? `def sum[T](name: String)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T] = Numeric[Double])`

Comment: @Jatin Thank you, I tried. But I got the error: value Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.type does not take type parameters. Scala ver: 2.11.12

Comment: The above line in the comment perfectly compiles.

Comment: @Jatin yes, It compiles but when I execute the method got the error. / def sum[T](name: String)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T] = Numeric[Double]): String = {"hello world!"} /  sum("abc") => error: ambiguous implicit values

Answer (score 4):

For this case you can use this trick:

```
trait A {
  def sum[T](name: String)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): String = numeric.zero.toString
}

object B extends A {
  def sum(name: String): String = sum[Double](name)
}

// use
val a = B.sum[Long]("name...")
val b = B.sum("name...")
```

[Working example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IVoz4ohoTGmfnU4kiQAJEw)

Of course you can `import B.sum` to refer to the function just as `sum`.